# Code to maintain session even after the browser window is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am setting the session during login like this `(Session["User_Type_1"] = 1;)`  but when I close the browser the session gets lost and value becomes null `Session["User_Type_1"]=null`

Comment: Sessions are not destroyed by closing the browser window. They would be destroyed after some idle time.

Answer (score 0):

it's about `sessionState` on your application configuration, these topic can help you

> [session Handling in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455840/session-handling-in-asp-net)

and

> [Changing the default value of session's variable timeout in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741775/changing-the-default-value-of-sessions-variable-timeout-in-asp-net-mvc)